# Requirement of 'fixed' seems inconsistent in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, fixed

I have an ordered struct which contains fields..

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public unsafe struct RunBlock_t {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]  public fixed byte raw[512];
}
```

If I declare this inside a function and want to use the pointer, it works fine..

```
{
  RunBlock_t r = new RunBlock_t();
  for (int i=0; i<512; i++) r.raw[i]=0;
}
```

But if I declare the variable outside the scope, it requires a fixed implementation

```
RunBlock_t r;
{
  r = new RunBlock_t();
  fixed (byte* ptr = r.raw) for (int i=0; i<510; i++) ptr[i]=0;
}
```

Why this difference in behavior?

--- EDITED -----

Just want to state again that any other permutation does not work.

```
    unsafe void foo() {
        RunBlock_t r = new RunBlock_t();
        fixed (byte* ptr = r.raw) for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++) ptr[i] = 0;
    }
```

Generates ***You cannot use the fixed statement to take the address of an already fixed expression*** and does not compile.

```
    RunBlock_t r;
    unsafe void foo() {
      r = new RunBlock_t();
      for (int i=0; i<512; i++) r.raw[i]=0;
    }
```

Generates ***You cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed expressions. Try using the fixed statement.*** and does not compile.

Comment: That... Actually is very inconsistent. Interesting. I would have expected both to need `fixed`.

Comment: @MarcGravell you seem to be answering all of my questions :) -- yeah, if I try using fixed in the first case, it gives me an error saying i cant use fixed on a fixed pointer.. (given that raw is already declared fixed in the struct)

Comment: @MarcGravell: What exactly about the first case (which subscripts an array and has no pointers whatsoever) would you expect to require `fixed`?

Comment: @Ben because *that is how you use them* - see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/

Comment: @Marc: That's a terribly useless link.

Comment: Your latest edit to the question, which moved the variable outside the function, not just outside the scope, makes a HUGE difference, because it's no longer ON THE STACK!

Comment: Sure, it's now in the heap; why would it be treated any differently?   It's just in a different memory location.

Comment: @reza: Because the garbage collector moves things around which are in the heap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have, unfortunately, confused the question slightly. If I copy from the question **exactly**, then this works fine:

```
    {
        RunBlock_t r = new RunBlock_t();
        for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++) r.raw[i] = 0;
    }
```

and this:

```
    RunBlock_t r;
    {
        r = new RunBlock_t();
        fixed (byte* ptr = r.raw) for (int i = 0; i < 510; i++) ptr[i] = 0;
    }
```

raises:

> You cannot use the fixed statement to take the address of an already fixed expression

And if we remove the `fixed`, it works.

What you should have shown was the function signature, i.e.

```
RunBlock_t r;
unsafe void Bar()
{
    {
        r = new RunBlock_t();
        fixed (byte* ptr = r.raw) for (int i = 0; i < 510; i++) ptr[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Now the meaning becomes clearer. You see, when you use `fixed` to access a fixed-buffer in a value, you aren't actually fixing the *buffer*, nor are you fixing the *value*; what you are *actually* fixing is the containing object, i.e. the object that has the `r` field.  This is to prevent GC from moving it around on the stack, which would be bad if we are accessing it as a pointer at the time. In our example above, our expression is really `fixed (byte* ptr = this.r.raw)`, and the thing that gets pinned is: `this`.

This is different if we **only** have a struct as a local. Locals are on the *stack*; they are (as the earlier message hinted) *already fixed*; the stack is never relocated by GC.

So:

- if you have a struct as a local variable, you do not need to use `fixed` - you are just accessing it as a pointer directly (via `ldloca`)
- if you have a struct that **is a field** in an object, you need to use `fixed`, to pin the object in place for the duration of your manipulations
- in cases where you're passing a *reference* to the struct (i.e. a `ref RunBlock_t` parameter), then you must use `fixed` **just in case** it is a field on an object; if the reference turns out to resolve to the stack, then it doesn't need to do anything
- note that everything here about "field on an object" also applies equally to "value in an array", i.e. if we are talking about `someArray[8]` (since you can manipulate the contents of arrays in-situ)

Comment: Good explanation of the difference between the code first shown, with local variables in two scopes, and the actual code posted later, with a class member.  Still not sure why the C# compiler would use a raw pointer to access a fixed buffer instead of a tracking pointer (aka `interior_ptr`).

Comment: thanks for the explanation!  So the field is fixed given the struct definition inside the struct, but not the actual structure.  So although r.raw is defined as fixed, it can still move around due to the GC.   And the stack is fixed by default, the heap is not.  And you need to do a heap alloc to make something fixed in the heap.  If you do that, can you cast the alloc'ed memory to a struct and access it that way?  Or is that just too ugly for c#?  Thnx again.

Comment: @reza yes, if you have a pointer (from an external alloc, or stackalloc, etc), you can coerce it as a struct You don't have to treat the entire thing as bytes

Comment: @Ben possibly because c# only declares one type of pointer, and it needs to work for all? It sounds more like a pin_street though...? (not really my area; the pin could also be happening explicitly)

Comment: @Marc: But we aren't limited to the pointer types exposed by C# to user code, the C# compiler generates MSIL which can use any semantics exposed by the CLR.  Which includes `interior_ptr` behavior (obviously it isn't called that in MSIL)

Comment: But probably someone on the C# team confused the two meanings of the `fixed` keyword (and this confusion may have made it into the spec).  But .NET does not require a fixed-*size* buffer to have a *fixed* address; the C# compiler's behavior makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

Your question doesn't make any sense.  You're confusing arrays with pointers, probably because in C and C++, and array quickly degrades to a pointer in most contexts, including the `[]` subscript operator.

But this is C#.  Arrays and pointers are completely separate beasts (although you can coerce an array to a pointer, you have to do so in a `fixed` statement, in order to make sure the pointer remains valid).  You should be comparing

```
{
  RunBlock_t r = new RunBlock_t();
  for (int i=0; i<512; i++) r.raw[i]=0;
}
```

to

```
RunBlock_t r;
{
  r = new RunBlock_t();
  for (int i=0; i<512; i++) r.raw[i]=0;
}
```

where both use arrays.  Or else

```
{
  RunBlock r = new RunBlock_t();
  fixed (byte* ptr = r.raw) for (int i=0; i<512; i++) ptr[i]=0;
}
```

to

```
RunBlock_t r;
{
  r = new RunBlock_t();
  fixed (byte* ptr = r.raw) for (int i=0; i<512; i++) ptr[i]=0;
}
```

where both use pointers.

And then you will see that the scope the variable is declared in has absolutely no relationship to needing `fixed`.

Comment: The 2nd case will not compile with a warning saying that i need to add a fixed in there.  The 3rd case will also fail saying that I can't apply a fixes statement to a fixed pointer (note that raw is fixed in the struct).

Comment: Here are there exact errors.  Case2: You cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed expressions. Try using the fixed statement.  Case3:You cannot use the fixed statement to take the address of an already fixed expressio

Comment: @reza: Failures in any of the code in my answer would be a compiler bug.  I'll see if I can get some of the Microsoft team members (for example Eric Lippert) to take notice.

Comment: A fixed buffer is not an array. There is no array shown in this question at all.

Comment: @Ben the member is a relative offset from the instance. In this case, offset zero. In every meaningful way, it is accessed as a pointer: I suspect (I didn't check) that if we look at the IL, there's a ldloca in there... And the result of ldloca is (quotes MSDN) "The result is a transient pointer (type *)."

Comment: From my perspective (heavy C background), it's all essentially the same thing - a pointer to a byte[] array.  Doesn't the fact that I can do this `(byte* ptr = r.raw)` mean that it is a pointer?

Comment: @reza important: a fixed buffer is not a vector, I.e not `byte[]`

Comment: @Ben see my answer for more context, in case I'm being obtuse

Comment: @Marc: Maybe it is `ldloca`.  But why not use `ldflda` or `ldelema`?  It's clearly possible to create a reference to a value type embedded on the heap without pinning the object, since that's how `ref` parameters work.  The same machinery *could* be used here, without fixing the object.

Comment: @Ben because when I said `ldloca` the example seemed to be referring to a local variable. Yes, with the edit showing it as a field it would be comparable to `ldflda` etc. I'll spin up reflector and look, though

Comment: @Ben yup, [`ldflda` there](http://pastie.org/5132829). I can only guess the actual pinning is via the CLI itself based on the various attributes on the compiler-generated `<raw>e_FixedBuffer0`

Comment: @Marc: It's referring to a field of a value type instance (which is a local variable in some cases).  For referring to a field, I should think that `ldflda` would be appropriate for all variants, and not require pinning.